# Process to interact with blob storage files from Databricks notebooks

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, databricks

Within a Azure Databricks notebook, I am attempting to perform a transformation on some csv's which are in blob storage using the  following:

```
*import os
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    os.chdir(r'wasbs://dalefactorystorage.blob.core.windows.net/dale')
    allFiles = glob.glob("*.csv") # match your csvs
    for file in allFiles:
       df = pd.read_csv(file)
       df = df.iloc[4:,] # read from row 4 onwards.
       df.to_csv(file)
       print(f"{file} has removed rows 0-3")*
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

*FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wasbs://dalefactorystorage.blob.core.windows.net/dale'

Am I missing something? (I am completely new to this).

Cheers,

Dale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use package `pandas` to read CSV file from Azure blob process it and  write
this CSV file to Azure blob in Azure Databricks, I suggest you mount Azure blob storage as Databricks filesystem then do that. For more details, please refer to [here](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#mount-azure-blob-storage-containers-to-dbfs).

For example

1. Mount Azure blob

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net":"<account access key>"})
```

[image]

2. process csv

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r'/dbfs/mnt/<mount-name>/<>')
allFiles = glob.glob("*.csv") # match your csvs
for file in allFiles:
    print(f" The old content of  file {file} : ")
    df= pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    print(df)
    df = df.iloc[4:,]
    df.to_csv(file, index=False,header=False)
    print(f" The new content of  file {file} : ")
    df= pd.read_csv(file,header=None)
    print(df)
    break
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jim Xu.  When trying to mount the blob, I am receiving the following error:
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container dale in account dalefactorystorage.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can&#39;t create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.
I have even tried with both access keys.

Comment: @dale Could you please check the container name in the storage account you use? According to the error, the container does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much Jim, that was the winner

Answer (score 0):

A, alternative approach is to mount the dbfs file as a spark dataframe, and then just convert it from a sparkdf to a pandas df:

```
# mount blob storage
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net",
"storageaccesskey")

dfspark = spark.read.csv("wasbs://containername@storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net
/filename.csv", header="true")

# convert from sparkdf to pandasdf 
df = dfspark.toPandas()
```